# Display Author role in archive or author page

Tags: author, user-roles

I want to display author role on archive and author page outside loop I found this code on stack overflow and it works fine within the loop

```
function get_author_role()
{
    global $authordata;

    $author_roles = $authordata->roles;
    $author_role = array_shift($author_roles);

    return $author_role;
}
```

In template using below code

```
echo get_author_role()
```

But when I am adding this to archive and author page its giving me warning message called

```
Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Any progress? Was my answer helpful? Do you still miss something?

Comment: Unfortunately, this code didn't work so I had to found another solution. I will post here.

Answer (score 1):

`$authordata` is not available before the first post is set up (before the first `the_post();`).

But all the *data* you need are already there on an author archive: in [`get_queried_object()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object/).

It is a `WP_User Object` on the author archive.

```
print '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( print_r( get_queried_object(), TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
WP_User Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [user_login] => toscho
            [user_pass] => $P$BO6.B4TIhxnKspIlxXHJCqa.M4I3v01
            [user_nicename] => toscho
            [user_email] => toscho@localhost.invalid
            [user_url] => 
            [user_registered] => 2011-12-25 15:20:12
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => toscho
        )

    [ID] => 2
    [caps] => Array
        (
            [author] => 1
        )

    [cap_key] => test_capabilities
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [0] => author
        )

    [allcaps] => Array
        (
            [upload_files] => 1
            [edit_posts] => 1
            [edit_published_posts] => 1
            [publish_posts] => 1
            [read] => 1
            [level_2] => 1
            [level_1] => 1
            [level_0] => 1
            [delete_posts] => 1
            [delete_published_posts] => 1
            [author] => 1
        )

    [filter] => 
)
```

So this will print the current author’s first role:

```
! empty ( get_queried_object()->roles )
    and print ucfirst( get_queried_object()->roles[0] );
```